# Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data

I get the following error with my spring beans,

> Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepositoryDAOImple':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSessionFactory'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable
>   to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Client.java

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
        EmployeeService employeeService = (EmployeeService) ctx.getBean("empoyeService");

        Employee employee1 = new Employee(100001, "Alex", "Account");
        Employee employee2 = new Employee(100002, "Sam", "HR");

        employeeService.insert(employee1);
        employeeService.insert(employee2);
        System.out.println("Records are successfully added..");
        ctx.close();

    }
}
```

Entity.java

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id
private int empId;
private String empName;
private String department;
public Employee() {
    super();
}
public Employee(int empId,String empName,String deptName)
{
    super();
    this.empId=empId;
    this.empName=empName;
    this.department=deptName;
}

public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}
public void setEmpId(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}
public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void setDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Employee Empid="+empId+" empName="+empName+" department="+department;
}


}
```

EmployeeService.java

```
@Service("empoyeService")
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository emprepo;
@Override
public void insert(Employee employee) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    emprepo.insert(employee);
}

@Override
public int delete(int empid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return emprepo.delete(empid);
}

}
EmployeeRepositoryDAOImple.java
   @Repository
   public class EmployeeRepositoryDAOImple implements EmployeeRepository{
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
@Override
public void insert(Employee employee) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(employee);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

}}
```

Config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<!-- Define Service and Repository beans using auto scan feature of         Spring -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.orm.employee.dao,com.orm.employee.Service" />

<!-- Define DataSource bean using DriverManagerDataSource class of Spring --> 
<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="xxxx"></property>
</bean>
<!-- Define sessionFactory bean of Spring class -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.orm.employee.dao" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```
Exception
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main"      org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepositoryDAOImple': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:676)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
at com.orm.employee.client.Client.main(Client.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:      Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:668)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
... 25 more
Caused by:     com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:353)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:336)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2938)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:855)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3337)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1217)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1930)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:716)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:353)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.getInstance(Connection.java:295)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
... 42 more
```

Comment: You need to post the full exception stacktrace, the message you show probably misses its end, so there might be other errors that cause JDBCConnectionException

Answer (score 9):

**Solution:**

Upgrading MySql connector jar from 5.1 to 8.0 fixed the problem - my code was not the problem.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by correcting mysql credentials in the src > main > `application.properties` file

Check if your mysql credentials are correct and mysql server is running.

Answer (score 3):

In my case didn't have the right autentication permission for root user.
I knew that because logged to database just only tipying that:

```
sudo mysql
```

So, once logged into MySQL I typed that:

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

And saw the value auth_socket in the plugin column of root user.
So, I typed that:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Then restarted tomcat and problem solved.

Henceforth, have to log into mysql typing:

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD
```

Hope It helps someone :)

Comment: A big time saver. Thanks @hfunes.com

Answer (score 3):

Check your Hibernate configuration:

```ini
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_boot_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=r00t
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in the timezone configuration. I added:

```
?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```

in application.properties. The whole line looked like this:

```
db.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/indigo?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the following changes to your code.

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

And add below property in addition and remove the `@Autowired` from sessionFactory

```
<bean id="employeeDAO" class="yourbasepackage.EmployeeRepositoryDAOImple"> 
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me

```
mysql>  CREATE USER 'scilla'@'172.17.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql>  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'scilla'@'172.17.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> flush privileges; 
mysql> exit


spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scilla
    username: scilla
    password: password
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    database: mysql
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, i recommand you to revise the way you are establishing the connection to the database via reviewing the configuration(application.properties):

```
## Spring Datasource Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/(package_name)?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****

## JPA Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you did up a image on docker for DB connection. This happens to me when I don't run Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

1.Test your mysql connection with the correct credentials
2.RE-run the spring boot application.